# Is using Chrome extention safe?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extensions, privacy

is using Google Chrome browser extension plugin safe in terms of online shopping ,banking,privacy and security.

i am an online shopper and excess to banking accounts regularly

what i want to know is do these plugins steal/use personal passwords,usernames etc ?

Comment: This is like asking whether using a car to get where you want to go is safe.  The concept of using plug-ins has nothing to do with safety.  There might be specific malicious plug-ins.  But nobody can make a blanket statement about all plug-ins affecting safety,  It's just a mechanism to add features.

Comment: i dont know how browser extentions work and quite not fuly aware of this matter cause i asked it[to clarify my hesitaion,douts]

Comment: @fixer1234 i have integrated Yellow Pen Highlighter for Web in Chrome browser but i had hesitation to use plugins for those reasons i mentioned above. i just wanted to clarify it and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Any extension you install has the possibility of monitoring keystrokes or form data so if you install a malicious plugin then you should consider all your account details compromised.

All plugins have the potential to steal all your data, you are essentially giving unknown code downloaded from the internet access  to everything your browser has access to. Without decompiling their code and poring over it for hours there is no easy way to tell what it is doing, just watching what it accesses is not enough as it is relatively easy to code to avoid suspicious behaviour as long as possible or to work around detection methods.

Whether any given plugin is exploitable is essentially unknowable, it depends on the skill of the plugin programmers as well as the browser programmers.

Chances are though as long as you avoid downloading from third party stores and only download long-standing and popular extensions you should be fine.

Comment: Your first three paragraphs are technically true, but you could say that about virtually every program.  That's the nature and risk of using a computer that connects to the Internet.

Comment: @fixer1234 I can't really argue with that as it was kind of what I was trying to get across. Extensions are programs that run within another program and the general advice for *any* program is to make an informed decision on whether or not you trust it.

Comment: @Mokubai I downloaded Yellow highlighter Pen for Web extension from Chrome webstore . Is chrome webstore third party and can i trust to this plugin? this is the first plugin i m installing to chrome browser.   pls enlighten me.

Comment: The Chrome website (https://chrome.google.com/webstore) is their main site so it is trustworthy in itself, but all the extensions are supplied by other people. Whether or not you trust them is up to you though. You would hope that highly popular or downloaded extensions have undergone some level of review or at least scrutiny by people using them but you can't guarantee it. As with any software you download you have to weigh up the utility verses the risks. Is it from a reputable source, yes. Is it respected and highly used? If so then you are likely fine, but I cant decide for you.

Comment: @Mokubai thanx mokubai thats a big chunk of awareness to me for the moment.